# Desaturate all images but selected using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem. I have a radio group selection where each radio input has a label with an image in it.

I'm trying to get all images to desaturate except from the selected image. If no selection  is made (initial state) then no effect should be made.

Belov is the HTML code. Any hints is very welcome.
Thanks!

#### Choose Payment Gateway

```
                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway1"><img src="img/deposit-0.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway1" class="gateway" />
                </div>

                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway2"><img src="img/deposit-1.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway2" class="gateway" />
                </div>

                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway3"><img src="img/deposit-2.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway3" class="gateway" />
                </div>

                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway4"><img src="img/deposit-3.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway4" class="gateway" />
                </div>

                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway5"><img src="img/deposit-4.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway5" class="gateway" />
                </div>

                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway6"><img src="img/deposit-5.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway6" class="gateway" />
                </div>

                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway7"><img src="img/deposit-6.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway7" class="gateway" />
                </div>

                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway8"><img src="img/deposit-7.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway8" class="gateway" />
                </div>

                <div class="gateway-container">
                    <label for="gateway9"><img src="img/deposit-8.png" alt="" /></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway9" class="gateway" />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the images of the non-selected radios:

```
$("input[name='gateway']:not(:checked)").prev("label").children("img").each(function() {
    //loops through each image corresponding to not checked radio buttons
});
```

I think this should be a good start!

Breaking down the selector:

`input[name='gateway']` selects all inputs that have the name `gateway`

`:not(:checked)` filters out all of the checked radio buttons from the `input[name='gateway']`

`.prev("label")` finds the previous `label` element

`.children("image")` gets the child image element of the previous label of the input.